# "Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the path specified." Not using IIS

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

This exact error has been posted many times here, and the resolution usually involved going into IIS and enabling "Application Pooling" or something like that.

I do not have IIS installed on this machine.

Alright, with that out of the way. Some code...

```
byte[] decryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(
    Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData),
    entropy,
    System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

> - System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the path specified.
>
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(Byte[]
>     encryptedData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope)
>     at .AmazonS3.AwsConfig.DecryptString(String
>     encryptedData) in
>     \AmazonS3\AwsConfig.cs:line 188
>     at DataAccessLib.AmazonS3.AwsConfig.GetAwsCredentials(String[]
>     addRecips) in
>     \AmazonS3\AwsConfig.cs:line 151

All I'm trying to do is decrypt some credentials, it works on several other machines... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Full stacktrace please? You can hit the code fragment button a few times after posting (and having the code selected), so you can indent your code correctly. Note that we don't know what is in the data or how it has been retrieved, and the error is likely linked to that.

Comment: The data being thrown into this call works on other machines. The same encrypted file is able to be decrypted on several test machines.

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Note that software, especially in the Microsoft universe, is often dependent on other software, and is often installed when you install that software. How much this is the case I found out when trying to install Visual Studio on my laptop and running out of a GB or three, some 12 years ago. Often it is installed, sometimes even without warning, when you install other software. So I'm not surprised that this could be a problem. However, I don't know what kind of system configuration you are on, or what installing IIS changes that makes the error go away.

Comment: I am seeing this same error returned - works fine in debug on my machine, returns this when run from a windows service. The same data is used, although the user is different; I wonder if the problem is within `DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser` and what that returns..? Very frustrating and as yet unsolved.

Comment: If there is a problem with the `CurrentUser`, it could be because decryption can usually only be done on the computer where the data was encrypted. A possible solution would be to encrypt the string in situ (I will try putting the unencrypted string in the app.config file to be encrypted the first time the app runs). Also, making sure that the encrypting user has a roaming profile and is the same user that unencrypts may yield results.